# ¿Como cargar los siguientes vídeos a continuación de los primeros?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy usando la api de youtube para cargar una playlist de vídeos en mi aplicación, toda la aplicación funciona con un paginador que es un botón de ver mas que carga mas contenido a continuación del contenido que ya hay, sin cambiar de pagina, estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo con los vídeos de youtube pero en vez de cargar mas vídeos a continuación de los que ya hay me los cambia, es decir se actualizan a los vídeos de la siguiente pagina, cuando yo lo que quiero es verlos todos en la misma pagina.

```
export const YoutubeList = () => {

    const API = 'borrada'
    const [allVideos, setAllVideos] = useState<any[]>([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState (false)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [nextPageToken, setNextPageToken] = useState ('')
   
   
        const fetchYoutubeList = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
       
        fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Csnippet&maxResults=20&playlistId=UULFYDxDmCQ_xfzk0ZnAkMt2WQ&order=date&key=${API}` )
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data.nextPageToken)
           
            setIsLoading(false)
          
            const result = data.items.map(item=> {
                return {title:item.snippet.title, vId:item.contentDetails.videoId, id:item.id, description:item.snippet.description, imgVideo:item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
            })
        
            setAllVideos(result)
           
            // setNextPageToken(data.nextPageToken)
        });
    
    }
  

    function getMoreVideos(){
        setIsLoading(true)
       
        fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Csnippet&maxResults=20&playlistId=UULFYDxDmCQ_xfzk0ZnAkMt2WQ&order=date&key=${API}&pageToken=`+nextPageToken)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data.nextPageToken)
            setIsLoading(false)
            const result = data.items.map(item=> {
                return {title:item.snippet.title, vId:item.contentDetails.videoId, id:item.id, description:item.snippet.description, imgVideo:item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
            })
        
            setAllVideos(result)
            setNextPageToken(data.nextPageToken)
        });
    }
   
    function handleAddToDetail(item) {
       
            dispatch(selectYoutube(item));
            navigate('youtubedetail');     
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       
        fetchYoutubeList()

    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="fixNotchMarginTop bg-teal-600 fixed block md:hidden w-full z-20 left-0 top-0 pt-2 pb-2 flex items-center justify-start header-top">
            <Link className="w-40 pb-3 font-medium text-xl text-white hover:text-white flex items-center" to="/">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-left stroke-white hover:stroke-white" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="18" />
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="6" />
                </svg>
                <span className="ml-2">Actualidad</span>
            </Link>
        </div>


        <div className="columns-1 mx-auto px-2 main-container pb-12">        
                {/* NewsCarousel */}
                <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 md:p-6 my-3 content-card">
                    <Link className="w-40 hidden md:flex pb-3 font-medium text-neutral-800 hover:text-teal-600 flex items-center" to="/">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-left stroke-neutral-800 hover:stroke-teal-600" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="18" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="6" />
                        </svg>
                        <span className="ml-2">Actualidad</span>
                    </Link>
                    {/* NewsList */}
                    {
                        allVideos.map(item => (
                            <div key={item.id} className="bg-white px-2 py-3 md:h-32 border-b rounded-0">
                                <button onClick={() => handleAddToDetail(item)} type="button" className="text-left overflow-hidden pb-2" >
                                    <div className="flex items-top flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center gap-2 md:gap-4">
                                        <img className="h-24 md:w-1/5 object-cover object-center rounded-md image-news" src={item.imgVideo} alt="youtubeImage" />
                                        <div className="md:w-4/5 ml-2 h-18">
                                            {/* <small className="text-teal-600 mb-2">{format ( new Date (news.creationDate), 'EEE dd/MM/Y HH:mm', { locale: es }).toUpperCase()}</small> */}
                                            <p className="text-lg text-neutral-800 font-medium news-title">{item.title}</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
               <button onClick={()=>getMoreVideos()}>ver mas</button>
            </div>
            {isLoading && <Loader />}

            

        </>
    )
```

Comment: intenta `setAllVideos([...allVideos, ...result])`

Comment: esa solución fue bien, gracias, el único problema que tengo es que al presionar la primera vez el botón ver mas me carga otra vez los primeros 20 vídeos, a partir de hay ya carga los siguientes correctamente, sabrías decirme el por que de este comportamiento?

Comment: Probablemente porque tienes comentado el setpagetoken en el primer llamado